# What does "xillybus_of_match[]" term in this struct assignment code signify?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

This block of code is taken from a tutorial on linux Kernel device drivers, and I am not sure how to interpret it. I am only asking about the C syntax. From my understanding of structs in C syntax follows the following convention ...

```
struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};
struct Books Book1;
```

But it seems like there is an additional term below "xillybus_of_match[]". What does this term mean in the C language?

```
static struct of_device_id xillybus_of_match[] __devinitdata = {
  { .compatible = "xlnx,xillybus-1.00.a", },
  {}
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, xillybus_of_match);
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the context shown, the variable `xillybus_of_match` is defined as an array, whose size is determined by the number of elements in the initializer list. And any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you that.

Comment: Yeah I know it is an array, but what role does it play in the struct assignment. I am assuming that of_device_id  is the struct type , and __devinitdata is the variable name, so what is xillybus_of_match ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The code, by itself, is not valid syntax, as `__devinitdata` is not a valid part of a declarator. Any decent book, tutorial, or class should have taught you that. It may be a macro that expands to some compiler extension. But if there are macros and compiler extensions in play, we cannot be certain of other aspects of the declaration without context. And you should not be chastising people who are learning in the presence of such complications.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't understand the `= {` and what follows [up to `};`]?

Comment: You're correct about `of_device_id` but `xillybus_of_match` is the variable name. `__devinitdata` is most likely a macro in the kernel source that uses compiler-extensions to put the data of the variable in a specific segment. I suggest you search the Linux header files for it.

Comment: I see that makes sense ... "#define __DEVINITDATA    .section   ".devinit.data", "aw" so you are correct it seems like its a macro. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form of a declaration starting with “`static struct` *tag-name*” is “`static struct` *tag-name* *declarator* `=` *initializer* [optionally more comma-separated declarators and initializers…]”, at least in the base C language defined by the standard.

A problem with this is that, although declarators can have various forms, none of them match `xillybus_of_match[] __devinitdata`. This opens up various possibilities involving preprocessor macros and/or compiler extensions.

From experience (because it is not generally taught in early books, tutorials, or classes), this form is used to provide compiler attributes or other language extensions. The `__devinitdata` may be a macro that is defined various ways according to circumstances such as which computing platform is begin targeted or which features are selected for building. It may be replaced with blank. In any case, the effect is likely that the declaration is equivalent to `static struct of_device_id xillybus_of_match[] = { *initial values* };`, possibly with some extra information added by the `__devinitdata`.

If so, then `xillybus_of_match` is declared to be an array whose number of elements is determined by the initializers and whose element type is `struct of_device_id`. The declaration also defines the array and initializes it with the initializers.

Compiling the code with the usual switches but with, using GCC or Clang, `-E` added and other switches affecting output (such as `-o`, `-S`) removed will produce the result of preprocessing, allowing you to see what `__devinitdata` is replaced with.

Comment: The keywords started with `__` in the declarations are usually compiler attributes. If in doubt, consult with Elixir kernel source tree browser. According to it the mentioned attribute had disappeared in v3.8: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.7/source/include/linux/init.h#L98